# Aplicacion compilada en Ionic no se instala

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-framework

Tengo un problema, estaba trabajando en una aplicación usando `Ionic`, todo normal hasta el momento de probar el `apk`, al pasarlo a mi celular y tratar de instalarlo, no se instala, el único **error** que me da es:

> Aplicación no instalada

No sé qué hago mal porque al compilar no me da ningún error. He usado varios comandos para la compilación, tanto leídos en foros como en la misma página de `Ionic`, me dejaron compilar el `apk` pero todos me dan el mismo **error**.

¿algún consejo o idea de cómo se arregla?

Answer (score 1):

El apk lo pasas de ionic a Android Studio con el comando `Ionic cordova build android --prod`?

Si no instala en tu Smartphone, te recomiendo bajar el nivel de API al de tu telefono.

EJ: Si tu telefono es un galaxy s6 con API 23 (Android 6.0), y usas una api 24(Android 7.0), deberas bajarla.
[Aqui](http://trucosandroidstudio.blogspot.com/2015/03/como-cambiar-nuestro-api-level-de.html) te dejo una guia de como bajar el nivel de Api.

Espero que sea de tu ayuda

Comment: yo también realicé el build android --prod y me logueó más errores que no permitía compilar mi aplicación por completo y no aparecian con simplemente hacer el build android solo, ahora estoy viendo de corregir esos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar **borrando la plataforma android** generada con el comando:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

y volviendo a generar:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

Ejecutar los siguientes comandos y cambiar el ID de aplicación:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android

<widget id="io.app.sistema" version="0.0.1"  ...

ionic cordova build android --prod -–release
```

**Note que si había otra app instalada con el mismo ID la aplicación no se instala.**

Comment: No tiene porqué no instalarse si está la misma instalada. Normalmente Ionic desinstala la aplicación si no puede actualizarla (si es la misma versión) y vuelve a instalarla.